# Usuário "Community" não teve seu perfil traduzido

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, tradução, localização

O usuário [**Community**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) - [que existe para todos os sites da rede](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738/177950) - mantém o nome e os dados do perfil em inglês. Seria interessante tê-los em português nesse site.

Nota: estou marcando isso como [localização](/questions/tagged/localiza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) e não [internacionalização](/questions/tagged/internacionaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) uma vez que - no meu entendimento - isso não envolve os devs; a infra-estrutura tal como está é suficiente para implementar isso (um mesmo usuário pode ter nomes diferentes e perfis diferentes em cada conta, mesmo que todas elas estejam vinculadas), basta editar. Se eu estiver enganado, favor corrigir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Houve uma sincronização desse perfil, e as traduções do nome e do *sobre mim* foram sobrescritas. Acredito que alguém da SE tenha editado o perfil-mestre e [disparado essa sincronização](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81345/167534).

Eu restaurei as traduções, mas pode acontecer novamente. Talvez perfis de sites localizados não devessem ser sobrescritos por sincronização, mas vejo vantagens e desvantagens nisso.